# PHP: Existant pdf to PDF/A

Tags: php, pdf, itext, ghostscript, pdfa

Hello Im I find pdfs hard to understand. I need to make existant pdf into pdf/a . I tried with GhostScript,

> 'gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK
>   -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 ...

But file gained alot in size. 700kb to 14Mb. Such size is not acceptable. I need alternative. anyone has any idea?

Comment: The most likely problem is that your original PDF file uses transparency. Transparency is forbidden in the PDF/A-1 specification (later versions permit it), and so any transparent areas will be rendered to an image, whihch will dramatically increase the file size. You need to either specify a later version of PDF/A, or accept the fact that this is going to happen. Your command line is also incomplete, as hinted at by Bruno below. While Ghostscript is quite capable of converting a PDF to PDF/A at the command line, you need to specify some more detail, such as the colour profile to be used.

Answer (score 0):

You should not expect a command line tool to be able to convert PDF to PDF/A. You should also not be surprised that a file grows in file size when you want to create a PDF/A document from a PDF.

To create a PDF/A from a PDF, you need to:

1. add XMP metadata,
2. embed all fonts that were previously not embedded (usually you can't do this from the command line because you'll need to provide a path to a font file in case a font program isn't found),
3. add a color profile,
4. remove all encryption,
5. remove JavaScript.

Unless the requirement is to create PDF/A-3, you may also have to convert all attachments to PDF/A.

Your question should be closed as off-topic as it does not contain a specific programming problem (e.g. some source code that we can fix). It is a very broad question and your expectation that you can do this without understanding PDF is too optimistic.

Your question also contains a contraction. In the subject line you mention PHP and in the tags you mention iText. iText is not a PHP library and you don't mention iText in your question anywhere.

Comment: I have been using itext to fill and flatten pdf in first place. Thanks for explaining it a bit to me, even though i could use a more accurate idea on how to tackle this and where to start

Comment: Your question is too broad and therefore unanswerable. Do you have a copy of ISO-19005? Do you know if you need PDF/A-1, PDF/A-2 or PDF/A-3? Is the original template already PDF/A compliant? Is the template an AcroForm or an XFA form?

Comment: yes i have basic 1.4 doc. it can be any pdf/a i think.... Any place where this stuff is explained for beginners like me?

Comment: Just in passing, Ghostscript *can* convert a PDF to PDF/A (more accurately, it can take a PDF file as input and produce a visually equivalent PDF/A output file), and it can be done from the command line. However, the command line supplied is insufficient to do this, there are additional parameters/PostScript code required, which has not been supplied here.